# Adding a dropdown to Cognos report prompt page

Tags: cognos

I am wondering if anyone has any cognos 10.2 experience. I need help creating a database dropdown prompt. So far I am not seeing anything in the toolbox other than some search box prompts and value prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If by dropdown prompt you mean a prompt in which its a single bar and you click the down arrow and choices cascade down? If so, then you need a value prompt.

Make the value prompt on your prompt page use the same query as your report and create a new parameter. Then highlight the prompt and in the properties pane make sure that it is the same query as the report, 'use value' is the query item that shows the values of your DB, and display value is the same query item.

that should work for you.

Comment: I would add that he should make sure that the 'Muli-Select' property is set to 'No' and the 'Select UI' property is set to 'Drop down list'. I believe this is the default. Different selections for those two properties will yield different UI elements, e.g a list box or check box group.